# What's the font being used on the HDMI logo?

Tags: fonts

Does anyone know what font that is used on the HDMI logo?
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:HDMI_Logo.svg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer you're looking for is called 'Gunship'..

Using the tool at whatfontis.com, it was able to recreate 'HDMI' in similar fonts, and the answer Gunship seems to match perfectly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would guess there is not a font for that, but the logo was artist designed..  For something close, you might look at [Porsche](http://www.ffonts.net/porsche.font).  It's not exact, but the letters have the same basic shape.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the right site for this sort of thing since we're not talking about the code used to make the typeface.

Most well-known logos aren't actually reproducible with a typeface, but rather start with a regular typeface and then are edited to be unique so they can't be easily copied. To rebuild a logo there are a couple of cool sites to look this sort of thing up in regards to fonts and typefaces:

[What the Font](http://www.whatthefont.com/) - lets you find a font name by uploading an image of the type.

[Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/identify.html) - lets you visually determine which attributes fit the typeface you’re trying to look up.

If the logo is extremely unique, then there is the chance that a typeface has been made in the style of the logo (think Coca-Cola).

One of the other posters recommended [Gunship](http://www.dafont.com/gunship.font?text=HDMI) which is available at the font distribution site [dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com/) which is mostly an offering of open source fonts.